# Automatically align dplyr pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

Is it possible to automatically align dplyr pipes in RStudio?

For example:

```
data %>%
    mutate(something = first + second) %>%
    select(first, something) %>%
    group_by(first) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(something))
```

Into:

```
data                                   %>%
    mutate(something = first + second) %>%
    select(first, something)           %>%
    group_by(first)                    %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(something))
```

Manytnx!

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  Change the indent from four spaces back to two and it will not directly contradict the tidyverse style guide (https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html) and it may help with readability.

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now, and I'm not sure RStudio team would find this very readable. However, you certainly can make your own add-in in RStudio that would be able to achieve this kind of alignment.

Comment: It is not. Feel free to file an issue on Rstudio's GH as a feature suggestion.